# Deitel How to program Android Cannon Game anonymous inner class warning

Tags: java, android

I'm coding through Deitel: Android How to program examples and in two of them my Android Studio gives warning/error on anonymous inner classes. It declares that Fragments should be static.

What's the correct way to go through this? If I make static non-anonymous inner class then there is no warning about the class, but I can't reference to non-static class variables(?). Other way could be to make a separate class (not inner class), but there is same problem with referencing variables.

This problem in with example Cannon Game, class CannonView, method showGameOverDialog (below) and also on FlagQuiz.

```
   private void showGameOverDialog(final int messageId) {

    final DialogFragment gameResult =
            new DialogFragment() {

                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));

                    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.result_format, shotsFired, totalElapsettime
                    ));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                                    newGame(); 
                                }
                            });
                    return builder.create(); 
                }
            };


    activity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showSystemBars(); 
                    dialogIsDisplayed = true;
                    gameResult.setCancelable(false);
                    gameResult.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "results");
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // display an AlertDialog when the game ends
    private void showGameOverDialog(final int messageId) {
        // DialogFragment to display game stats and start new game
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));
        // display number of shots fired and total time elapsed
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                R.string.results_format, shotsFired, totalElapsedTime));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // called when "Reset Game" Button is pressed
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                        dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                        newGame(); // set up and start a new game
                    }
                }

        );
        /*       final DialogFragment gameResult =
                new DialogFragment() {
                    // create an AlertDialog and return it
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
                        // create dialog displaying String resource for messageId
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));

                        // display number of shots fired and total time elapsed
                        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.results_format, shotsFired, totalElapsedTime));
                        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    // called when "Reset Game" Button is pressed
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                        dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                                        newGame(); // set up and start a new game
                                    }
                                }
                        );

                        return builder.create(); // return the AlertDialog
                    }
                };
*/
        // in GUI thread, use FragmentManager to display the DialogFragment
        activity.runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        final AlertDialog gameResult = builder.create();
                        showSystemBars();
                        dialogIsDisplayed = true;
                        gameResult.setCancelable(false); // modal dialog
                       // gameResult.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "results");
                        gameResult.show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: This is the same version I first tried, but the problem here is that variables shotsFired and totalElapsetTime are not static, so they can't be used in a static metod. Also metodi newGame is not static.

Comment: One  - but not very elegant - way to go around this is to make additional static variables (use them in this metod), copy the non-static values to them just before this metod showGameOverDialog above is called. But I wish there would be a better way.